# react bootstrap-table csv exporting with mimetype

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a react bootstrap-table with the exportCSV option set. I have been asked to add the "text/html" mimeType to the exported csv. Is there anyway to add this as an option?

A very basic view of the table in question is:

```
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
export class Table extends Component {
    constructor() {}
    render() {
        return(
            <BootstrapTable data={this.tableData} exportCSV >
            ... // TableColumns etc
            </BootstrapTable>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

I believe it is always exported as `text/plain;charset=utf-8`

The code for the exporting can been seen [here](https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/blob/26d07defab759e4f9bce22d1d568690830b8d9d7/src/csv_export_util.js#L68).

Answer (score 0):

yes, you would be able to add the mimeType & Encoding you would like. You can do something like,

````
<ToolkitProvider
   exportCSV={{```       
         blobType: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8',   
       }}
</ToolkitProvider>
````

[Docs](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/export-csv-props.html#exportcsvblobtype-string)